# How to read and decrypt dynamodb stream update event?

Tags: encryption, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I store our data in a dynamodb table and on every update, a listener lambda (in Java) receives an update from the dynamodb stream. I was parsing the dynamodb update event using JacksonConverter

However, I would like to encode the dynamodb content in the tables. So, I can't use the JacksonConverter directly.

I would like to know if anyone has done the decryption of data from the dynamodb stream and did you use any libraries?

I use DynamodbMapper's AttributeTransformer to encode the stuff. Can I use the same for decrypting the output from this stream too?

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach seems to call the DDB using the un-encrypted attributes, if the use-case allows so.